# Bounce balls from each other (LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing an Android game with the game development framework libgdx.
I would like to bounce multiple balls from each other. My method isCircleCollision works fine. But when I try this code, the balls sometimes appear in a collsion at a random place. They wouldn't set to the minimum translation distance.

```
    public void moveBalls(float t) {
        // loop through all balls
        for(int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
             Ball ballA = balls.get(i);
             float vx = ballA.getVx(); // velocity x
             float vy = ballA.getVy(); // velocity y
             float x  = ballA.getX();  // position x
             float y  = ballA.getY();  // position y

             // check if ball collide with other ball
             for (int j = i + 1; j < balls.size(); j++) {
                   Ball ballB = balls.get(j);
                   float radius = BALL_SIZE / 2;
                   float pointXA = x + radius;
                   float pointYA = y + radius;
                   float pointXB = ballB.getX() + radius;
                   float pointYB = ballB.getY() + radius;
                   if(Collision.isCircleCollsion(pointXA, pointYA, pointXB, pointYB, radius, radius)) {
                       // vector between pointA and pointB
                       Vector2 delta = ballA.getPosition().sub(ballB.getPosition());
                       float distance = delta.len();

                       // calculate minimum translation distance vector
                       Vector2 mtd = delta.scl(((radius + radius) - distance) / distance);

                       // add mtd
                       x += mtd.x * 0.5f;
                       y += mtd.y * 0.5f;
                       ballB.setX(ballB.getX() - mtd.x * 0.5f);
                       ballB.setY(ballB.getY() - mtd.y * 0.5f);
                 }
             }

             vx = vx + Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() * ACCEL_X_FACTOR;
             x -= t * vx;
             y -= t * vy;

             ballA.setVx(vx);
             ballA.setVy(vy);
             ballA.setX(x);
             ballA.setY(y);
        }
    }
```

Variable f is the frame delta time.

vy is set to 60f.

All the balls have the same size.

Here is an example with two balls with a radius of 2:

[image]

```
ballAPoint = (2;2)
ballBPoint = (5;4)
radius     = 2
distance   = sqrt((5-2)^2 + (4-2)^2) = 3,61

delta = (3;2)

// delta * ((radius + radius) - distance) / distance

mtd = delta * ((2 + 2) - 3,61) / 3,61 = (0,324, 216)

mtd.x / 2 -> x intersection
mtd.y / 2 -> y intersection
```

This seems to be working, but sometimes a ball appear on a random place on the screen.

What went wrong?

Comment: What is the assertion after `Vector2 mtd = delta.scl(((radius + radius) - distance) / distance);`? Let's say `distance` becomes very small, then `Vector2 mtd = delta.scl(((radius + radius) - distance) / distance);` can result in mtd becoming a long Vector2. (I have othre reservations, but this should be cleared up first.)

Comment: I use the mtd vector to avoid intersection between the balls

Comment: If `distance < 2*radius`, what should be the result of this scaling operations? If `distance == radius`, the factor is 1.0. If `distance == 0.5*radius`, the factor is 3.0, and it'll increase to infinity with decreasing distance.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Check for the maximum value of scaling factors `(radius + radius) - distance) / distance`. Values significantly larger than 1 might appear to throw balls far away from the point of collision. (2) A ball can be bounced more than once, because the position of `ballB` is updated immediately after collision with some `ballA`. A copy of the List should be made, and all collisions for time t should be computed using the old list.

Comment: Can you provide some ball data and the values of the finals (BALL_SIZE, ACCEL_X_FACTOR)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The BALL_SIZE has the value 80 and the ACCEL_X_FACTOR 1.5f. The vy of the balls are constant (60f). The vx of the balls has the value of vx + Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() * ACCEL_FACTOR_X. Should I use the copy of the list in the second for loop where I check if a ball collide?